# Python: Calculating multinomial coefficients regarding specific partitions

Tags: python-3.x, math

In my code, I am calculating all possible partitons and their repetition count. After profiling, the main reason why everything takes so long is the last 'counting'. The number of partitions with repetitions is defined as N!/(k1!k2!k3!...k_m!) Where N is the entire number of slots and k1... Is the number of one single element appearing in the partition, m being the number of unique elements appearing.

[Edit: This formula describes the multinomial coefficient of n over (k1,k2,...,km).]

My code to that looks like this:

```
Def calcOptions(c)
  return nFac // math.prod(map(math.factorial, collections.Counter(c).values()))
```

c is a list of one partition, with counter I get a list of how often several numbers appear within that partiton.
Since I will be calling this function a lot, I tried to minimize lines and working time, also numpy didn't make it better, it even got worse regarding computational time.
I thought of memorizing the different results of math.prod, but I think the resulting matrix/ dict would be gigantic thus taking more RAM which is already maxed out with this implementation.
Also I already am threading the entire workload, I thought of converting the entire program to c/c++ but I think I have to deal with this problem first.
Is there any way to improve this further?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on number partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) contains recurrence formulas, both for the number of all partitions and for the number of partitions into `k` parts. Using such recurrences will be more efficient than trying to work them out directly via factorials.

Comment: You might be intereested in sympy's module partitions: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/combinatorics/partitions.html

Comment: @JohnColeman In this program, I am trying to calculate the "portion" of one partition on the set of all partitions. Thank you for the idea, but I can't find any formula concerning just one partition since that might be the formula i mentioned in the original question :/

Comment: Your question might be easier for others to understand if you give some examples of explicit inputs and outputs.

Comment: Are you just trying to compute multinomial coefficients?

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for that advise, I totally forgot about it.
Assume u have 3 slots and u have to get the partitions of 8. The program calculates at first all non repeating Partitions:
[[8, 0, 0], [7, 1, 0], [6, 2, 0], [5, 3, 0], [4, 4, 0], [6, 1, 1], [5, 2, 1], [4, 3, 1], [4, 2, 2], [3, 3, 2]]
For the Partition [8,0,0] we get 3, and for [7,1,0] we get 6.
-> [3, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 6, 6, 3, 3]

Comment: Yes, I am calculating the multinomial coefficient of (n, (k1,k2...km)). I am editing the question to point that out directly

Comment: I took a look at other Questions regarding multinomial coefficients directly, but it appears that the use of factorial actually might be fast already

Comment: I wrote a version of multinomial that calculated it as a product of binomial coefficients. It is measurably faster than the factorial approach, but even when run millions of times the total speed-up is less than a second. So you are correct that the factorial-based approach is adequately fast.

Comment: My program is supposed to calculate averages of a function over all partitions of a given maximum set of a sum and slots, e.g 20 slots and a sum of 100 (and any combination below that). The number of calls of this function that I asked my question about should go into a high number of millions if not even billions...